# Python scripts can't load Django settings module -- ImportError

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a Django project on Mac OS X in a virtual environment and have a few regular Python scripts that I need to run for some stuff (mostly manipulating data). However, every time I try to run one of these scripts that uses anything from Django, such as importing a model, fails wit this error:

```
ImportError: Could not import settings 'myproject.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named myproject.settings
```

I've added the following lines to the top of the script:

```
import sys
import os

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myproject.settings'

sys.path.append("path/to/project/")
```

I even print out the sys.path and I can see the path to the folder container myproject there. But still I get the same error. Any ideas on what I can do?

---

When I run `python -m modulefinder my-script.py`, I get modules from my root Python path (the default is the Enthought distribution) and from my venv path.

Comment: You can check the modules and packages that are loaded by doing `python -m modulefinder <your-script>.py`

Comment: Good advice -- I ran that and nothing from Django shows up at all, and nothing at all from the Django path -- is there a way to add this to the venv I'm running?

Comment: Is this a Windows or Linux install?

Comment: @Mike: modulefinder? Keeerist! It's been in there since 2.3 and this is the first I've heard of it. This is the 3rd "new" stdlib module I've heard of in the last month. Guess I need to take the day off and read all of the the 2.7.x docs from top to bottom.

Comment: your script, does it start under virtualenv or from system? Do you have Django installed in system and/or virtualenv?

Comment: the script starts in virtualenv and Django is installed in that virtualenv, running `yolk -l` shows it as `Django          - 1.4.2`

Comment: Is your settings.py in path/to/project/ or in path/to/project/myproject?

Answer (score 2):

You need to django.setup()

```
import os
import django

# Connect to the Django Database 
script_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']='myapp.settings'
django.setup()
```

Comment: I search for this hours... Thank you!